# Html5,jquery mobile android/iphone application

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, html

I am building an application for andriod/Iphone using jquery mobile ,html5

I need to show a graph and below it will be a slider.

I have implemented the slider using jquery mobile.

But I need to know how can I show graph , the graph needs to change as I slide the slider.

Does the simple graphs in javascript like "Rgraph" will work in offline mobile application I am building or there is some special graph library in jquery for mobile application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try scencha charts, it is widlely used in mobile websites.  [scencha examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch-charts-rc/examples/)

Comment: Thanks , that looks promising.I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that HTML5 is only supported on  modern mobile browsers.

To detect changes on your slider :

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
  // Do Some Chart Processing ...
});
```

For more information about mobile browsers support for HTML5, please refer to this [article](http://caniuse.com/).